# convert list comprehension to normal for loop in python

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension

```
nums = [1,2,3]
result = [[]]
for num in nums:
    result.extend([subset + [num] for subset in result])
return result
```

**Here is my code**:

```
nums = [1,2,3]
result = [[]]
for num in nums:
    for subset in result:
        result.extend([subset + [num]])
return result
```

I tried to rewrite it using nested for loop, but it went into infinite.
I'm wondering why list comprehension works fine while normal for loop doesn't work.
Thank you.

Comment: Show us the code that "went infinite".  We can't explain the error if we don't know what you tried.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in the list comprehension version a copy of `result` is taken and then operations were done, while in for loop version you keep extending `result` while iterating which will result in an infinite loop.

You can use a copy of `result` for each loop and this way you will get the same result, for example:

```
nums = [1,2,3]
result = [[]]
for num in nums:
    for subset in result[:]:
        result.extend([subset + [num]])
print(result)
```

Using slicing, `result[:]` returns a copy of `result` and not `result` itself

Output:

```
[[], [1], [2], [1, 2], [3], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a list to be appended to `result` then extend `result` with that list. That's what the comprehension shortcuts.

```
nums = [1,2,3]
result = [[]]
for num in nums:
    subsets = []
    for subset in result:
      subsets.append(subset + [num])
    result.extend(subsets)
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the same as your code:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    nums = [1, 2, 3]
    result = [[]]
    for num in nums:
        for subset in list(result):
            result += [subset + [num]]
    print(result)
```

I assume you had something similar, but used

```
for subset in result:
```

instead of

```
for subset in list(result):
```

I suppose your loop was infinite, because you iterated over the same list which you extended in each iteration. you need to loop over a copy of your list instead...